Create a team webinar using Graph API
I am trying to create a webinar in team using my user as the presenter. In order to do that, I used the tutorial that is provided by Microsoft at this page : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/virtualeventsroot-post-webinars?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http . The site is date at 2024-08-08, which is not that far ago so I would trust it.
For the moment, I use the Graph API Explorer as it simplified the login process (https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/graph-explorer)
I use the sample they give on the page (with no modification except the user and tenant id) :
{     
"displayName": "The Impact of Tech on Our Lives",
"description": {
  "contentType": "text",
  "content": "Discusses how technology has changed the way we communicate."
},
"startDateTime": {
  "dateTime": "2024-03-30T10:00:00", 
  "timeZone": "Pacific Standard Time" 
},
"endDateTime": {
  "dateTime": "2024-03-30T17:00:00", 
  "timeZone": "Pacific Standard Time" 
},
"audience": "organization",
"coOrganizers": [
  {
    "id": "7b7e1acd-a3e0-4533-8c1d-c1a4ca0b2e2b", 
    "tenantId": "77229959-e479-4a73-b6e0-ddac27be315c" 
  }
],
"settings": {
  "isAttendeeEmailNotificationEnabled": false
}

}
No matter what I do, I always get a 400:  Bad Request with no explanations. I checked the autorization and they only mention VirtualEvent.ReadWrite for delegated user (which I do) and my user has it.
I tried the following

Using another user : Same result
Using an application user : Forbidden, but this was expected since there doesn't seem to be a way withouth delegation.
Remove some attributes : I can see that if I remove an attribute that must be required that the message change. If I remove the display name, I get a specific message stating that the field is required. Otherwise, I get the same error.
Tried Put and Patch method. No result, they don't exist at all
Use Beta instead of 1.0 : Same result

So my question is in two parts :

Was anyone able to create a team webinar using the graph api and if so, can I get a sample ?
What am I doing wrong ? I do exactly what the site tells me yet it won't do it.

Note : Creating is the only thing I can't do. Once a webinar is created "manually", I can easily access its info.

Make sure that the user account you are using has the necessary permissions. You mentioned that you have the VirtualEvent.ReadWrite permission, which is correct for creating webinars. and The endpoint should be solutions/virtualEvents/webinars as per the Microsoft documentation.

I doubled and maybe even triple check that I am using the right user, which is mine and he has that permission. As for the endpoint, as far as I can see, it is that exact one with the post method.

Yeah even I tried it in several ways and got the same error

This is actually a relief to see someone else have the same issue. Still, either it's on Microsoft end or something I'm doing is off, or not documented.

We have logged a bug for the above issue. We will keep you posted on the updates. Thank you.

FYI:
I got the same result, but when I did a graph call to list the events, they were there???
I saw in the docs that events created using this API dont appear in your calandar, but I cannot find that at this time...

I ll try when I get back but I didn't see it appear at all.
